# Visual Basic C# output is unexpected

Tags: c#

Visual Basic and C#
Just learning the basics and the output from these very simple few lines confuses me.

```
int x = 10;
int y = x++;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

The output is 11 and then 10. I was expect 10, then 11. What am I missing here?

Comment: `x++` means as; _return `x` **then** increment its value_. That's why when you write them `x` will be `11` but `y` will be `10`.

Comment: `int y = x++;` assign 10 to `y` because you use `x++`(postfix increment) instead of `++x`(prefix increment). But **after** this `x` is changed to `11`. See: [++ Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

Comment: Thank you and apologies for duplicate

Answer (score 2):

`x++` increments `x` after its usage (so in your example after assigning its current value to `y`). `++x` on the other hand increments `x` before it is used. So

```
int x = 10;
int y = ++x;   // Note that the plus signs stand before x, not after!
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

would lead to

> 11
>
> 11

If you want to assign `x+1` (`11`) to `y` and leave `x` at `10` do

```
int x = 10;
int y = x + 1;
Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

> 10
>
> 11

Answer (score 0):

`y = x++` will assign first and then increment. `y = ++x` will increment first, then assign. In your example, you are first assigning `y` the value of `x`, then incrementing `x` to `11`.

As `int` is a [value type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) (compared to a reference type), changing the value of `x` won't affect the value assigned to `y`.

```
int x = 10;
int y = x++; // Assigns the value of x to y (i.e. 10), THEN incrementing x to 11.
Console.WriteLine(x); // Writes the current value of x (i.e. 11).
Console.WriteLine(y); // Writes the current value of y (i.e. 10).
```